# How to pass another parameter in url_for inside an anchor tag

Tags: python, flask

I would like to pass another parameter in the below url_for inside an anchor tag.

```
<a href="{% if app.percent_complete==None %}{{url_for('survey')}}{% else %}{{url_for('shortview')}}{% endif %}?survey_id={{app.survey_id}}"
```

so along with survey_id, I also want to pass app_id.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would move both the condition and the parameters into the `url_for` call. Now it is possible to pass more parameters to `url_for`.

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('survey' if app.percent_complete is None else 'shortview', survey_id=app.survey_id, app_id=app.id) }}">Link</a>
```